# React-Native componentWillRecieveProps rendering issue

Tags: react-native

In my RN project, I want to achieve this.

// componentWillReceiveProps
    componentWillReceiveProps = async (nextProps) => {
        let { searchText, peopleTab } = this.props;

```
    let params = {};

    if (peopleTab !== nextProps.peopleTab) {
        params.peopleTab = nextProps.peopleTab;
    }

    // here i want to pass nextProps.searchText without a condition with the params like this.
    // params.searchText = nextProps.searchText

    if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
        await this.props.fetchUnfollowedPeople(params);
    }
}
```

I want to send nextProps.searchText with params object, if there is a new value. Otherwise I want to send this.props.searchText with the params object.

The above code, if I uncomment

```
 // params.searchText = nextProps.searchText
```

it gives the infinity loop. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `let { searchText, peopleTab } = this.props;` in `componentWillReceiveProps` causes the new value to be pasted

```
componentWillMount() {
   this.searchText = this.props.searchText ;
   this.peopleTab = this.props.peopleTab ;
}

componentWillReceiveProps = async (nextProps) => {

    const params = [];

    if (this.peopleTab !== nextProps.peopleTab) {
         params['peopleTab'] = nextProps.peopleTab ;
    }

    if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
        await this.props.fetchUnfollowedPeople(params);
    }
}
```